Duke Nukem 3D .con files for ammo
Can anyone help me out with .con files for eDuke32 for carrying up to 999 of each ammo? I made some attempts to create a basic user.con but keep getting startup errors.
Looking at the log, it might actually be game.con that I need. All the errors relate to that (loads of undefined variables when using the original DOS .CONs). I guess when you drop in a user.con, eDuke32 expects at least a game.con in addition to that?

Man, That's an old game. Nice that these old games are still getting attention.

I replay it every year or two :-) Along with Doom, Heretic, Dark Forces, Outlaws etc
